# Aeson with arrays of arrays, of which some are empty

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have the unfortunate data to work with:

```
{ "name": "foo"
, "data": [ []
          , ["a", "b", "c", 1]
          , ["d", "e", "f", 2] ] }
```

The data entries are allowed to be either empty array, or an array of size four.

That I want to parse into:

```
data ResultRow = ResultRow Text Text Text Int deriving (Show, Generic)

data ResultSet =
  ResultSet { f_name :: Text
            , f_data :: [Maybe ResultRow] } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

The following however does not accept the empty arrays:

```
customOptions = defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = drop 2 }

instance FromJSON ResultRow where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON customOptions
instance FromJSON ResultSet where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON customOptions
```

The error message is:

```
Left "Error in $[1].data[0]: When expecting a product of 4 values, encountered an Array of 0 elements instead"
```

I've also tried putting an extra type around `[Maybe ResultRow]` and have that convert the sub-arrays to lists and pattern match on `[]`, and dispatch the non-empty case to the `ResultRow` parser but I simply couldn't get it to compile and got lost in the error messages.

Ideally I would like to have some way of skipping the empty arrays as they're just noise in the data. I have no control of the producer of the data.

Comment: in this case I wouldn't use the generic json parser, instead I would write it on my own using the combinators from aeson!

Comment: Are you saying that this is impossible / unfeasible with the generic json parser, or you just don't know how to do it and thus recommend the combinators in a comment rather than an answer? Do you have any reading material to suggest that explores somewhat similar in-data as I have, using the combinators you mention?

Comment: try Maybe [ResultRow] instead of [Maybe ResultRow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like *dsvensson*, I'm puzzled that this doesn't 'just work' out of the box, since both `[a]` and `Maybe a` are `FromJSON` instances when `a` is. Since I already ended up spending way too much time on this, I can't offer an *explanation*, but I can offer a workaround. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can give a better answer.

Instead of defining `f_data` as a `[Maybe ResultRow]`, you can define a `newtype` that wraps `Maybe ResultRow`:

```
newtype MaybeResultRow = MaybeResultRow (Maybe ResultRow) deriving (Show, Generic)
```

You can give this type special `FromJSON` behaviour:

```
instance FromJSON MaybeResultRow where
  parseJSON v =
    case fromJSON v of
      Success rr -> return $ MaybeResultRow $ Just rr
      _          -> return $ MaybeResultRow Nothing
```

This, obviously, implies a change of `ResultSet`:

```
data ResultSet =
  ResultSet { f_name :: Text
            , f_data :: [MaybeResultRow] } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

In order to test, I defined this JSON document:

```
myJson :: ByteString
myJson =
  "{\
     \\"name\": \"foo\",\
     \\"data\": [\
        \[],\
        \[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\", 1],\
        \[\"d\", \"e\", \"f\", 2]\
     \]\
   \}"
```

Loading it all into GHCi, it looks like it's working:

```
*Lib Lib> decode myJson :: Maybe ResultSet
Just (ResultSet {
          f_name = "foo"
        , f_data = [
                     MaybeResultRow Nothing,
                     MaybeResultRow (Just (ResultRow "a" "b" "c" 1)),
                     MaybeResultRow (Just (ResultRow "d" "e" "f" 2))]})
```

Here, I've taken the liberty to format the output from GHCi in order to enhance readability.

I trust that you can figure out how to unwrap and filter the list of `MaybeResultRow` values...

I stole the solution of using `fromJSON` and matching on `Success` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913449/126014).